# Cannot send drupal_http_request authorization header

Tags: 7

I'm trying to post a request using drupal_http_request, but my headers are causing authorization errors.

This is my request:

```
$headers =  array('Authorization'=>'Bearer [my token here]', 'Content-Type'=>'application/json' );
$url = "https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications";
$message= new stdClass();
$message->message='That works';
$message->title='titleofmessage';
$data = array('tokens' => array('DEV-f765ac70-1bcb-4e0f-8bfd-adfd9612f185'), 'profile'=>'fake_push_profile', 'notification'=>$message);
$result=drupal_http_request($url, $headers, 'POST', json_encode($data));
```

In cURL it works fine, but I want to use drupal_http_request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer [my token here]" -d '{"tokens": ["DEV-f765ac70-1bcb-4e0f-8bfd-adfd9612f185"],"profile": "fake_push_profile","notification": {"message": "That works", "title": "titleofmessage"}}' "https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications"
```

The error message I get is 'Authorization header is missing' so something seems to be happening to that header.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the second param to `drupal_http_request` wrong; it should be an array of options, not an array of headers. Headers is just one of those options.

To fix:

```
$result = drupal_http_request($url, array('headers' => $headers), 'POST', json_encode($data));
```

Comment: Thanks Clive. You are right, but it still didn't work for me. That made me recheck the documentation for drupal_http_request and it seems i've been using the drupal 6 notation. My request should have been

     $options=array('headers'=>$headers, 'data'=>json_encode($data), 'method'=>'POST');
 
 $result=drupal_http_request($url, $options);

Answer (score 1):

While Clive was right for Drupal 6, I am using Drupal 7. I've marked his answer as correct, but the code I ended up using was:

```
$headers =  array('Authorization'=>'Bearer [my token here]', 'Content-Type'=>'application/json' );
$url = "https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications";
$message= new stdClass();
$message->message='That works';
$message->title='titleofmessage';
$data = array('tokens' => array('[device token]'), 'profile'=>'fake_push_profile', 'notification'=>$message);

$options=array('headers'=>$headers, 'data'=>json_encode($data), 'method'=>'POST');

$result=drupal_http_request($url, $options);
```